# Mobile Safari rendering bug? Black Box on site

Tags: rendering, mobile-safari

Hey there I build a website a long time ago and now I noticed that there is a bug on my site!

If users open the page on a ios device with ios 6 in the safari app there is a black box on the bottom of the content box! (See screenshot below)

On other browsers like firefox or google chrome and also on safari for mac all looks fine.

The URL of the site is http://rsaschheim.de

Hope someone can help!

Thanks Laurenz

**iOS 6 screenshot with Bug:**

[image: iOS 6 screenshot with Bug]

**iOS 5 screenshot without Bug:**

[image: iOS 5 screenshot without Bug]

Comment: I can not replicate this bug in iOS 6. Does the issue remain? Have you tested in Safari using the console?

Comment: seems to be fixed in the current ios version... Thanks 4 u help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be fixed in the current iOS Version.